# 0 x 0 Relative Div Still Taking Up Room

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a web page with a small label off to the right of the body on some lines. For this, I created an absolute-positioned `<div>` inside of a relative-positioned one.

The label is appearing exactly as I want it. However, even though the absolute-positioned `<div>` dimensions are 0 x 0, it still is taking up some room on the line.

This can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/sznH2/. I would like the two buttons to line up vertically. Instead, the button next to the label is pushed left a few pixels.

Can anyone see what is causing this spacing and how to eliminate it?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button>Hello world!</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button>Hello world!</button>
        <div class="outer-relative">
            <div class="inner-relative">
                <span>XXX</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.pull-right {
    text-align: right;
}
.outer-relative {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    height: 0px;
    width:0px;
}
.inner-relative {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -15px;
    background-color: Lime;
}
```

Comment: A solution that solely gets rid of the symptoms in IE is `margin-left: -4px;` in the `outer-relative` class. I am not 100% sure why this problem happens tho, so I hope that someone answers with a better solution.

Comment: if the div has to be 0x0 px...why not use a display:none?

Comment: @Sumurai8 check out my answer, its because of 'inline-block'

Comment: @RyanS I knew inline-blocks collapse around their content, but I never realized they did so around spaces. It can also be fixed by simply making it a block instead of an inline-block. I gave you a +1 ;-)

Comment: @peorthyr The relative div is only used to have a starting position to absolute position the child div. If he would do `display: none`, it will hide that element, and it's child elements. Obviously that is not what he wants, because the absolute positioned element would be hidden too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inline block elements will render the spacing between the tags. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/sznH2/4/

```
<button>Hello world!</button><div class="outer-relative"><div class="inner-relative"><span>XXX</span>
```

Remove the spaces and you're good to go

Comment: Your explanation is correct but your fiddle seems to not demonstrate what you wrote about.

Answer (score 0):

I think You Need to make pull-right postiton:relative
and outer-relative absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/tousif123/sznH2/3/

is this what are you looking for?

```
.pull-right {
    position:relative;
}

.outer-relative {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any reason to alter the `position` value for those rows that do not show the label.